# Como traer datos de una BD MYSQL a ANDROID para se me muestre en un activity

Tags: android, json

Al entrar a un activity me jale de la Base de datos, e buscado en tutoriales y todos lo hacen al presionar un Boton (OnClick) pero en este caso quiero que me muestren datos al entrar sin necesidad de un boton ni de ingresar el Id.

```
btn_mostrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buscarProducto("http://192.168.0.10/php/mostrarCambio.php");
            }
        });


        }

    private void buscarProducto(String URL){
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                for (int i=0; i<response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        edt_DatoCompra.setText(jsonObject.getString("compra"));
                        edt_DatoVenta.setText(jsonObject.getString("venta"));
                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR DE CONEXION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
            );
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Llama al método `buscarProducto()` desde el `onStart()`

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onstart();
    buscarProducto("http://192.168.0.10/php/mostrarCambio.php");
}
```